# Webgl program drawing 3D shapes

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

This is my first time posting here and i have a problem in my code that i can't figure out. The code is posted here:

https://github.com/thenash654/Coursera/blob/master/EXAMPLES/Assignment%203.js
https://github.com/thenash654/Coursera/blob/master/EXAMPLES/Assignment%203.html

The purpose of the program is to make different solid in space. I am able to draw all solids and can change the position IN the code (by changing the array "centre" defined in the js file). However, if i try to change the centre of the solid using the HTML sliders, the polygon messes up. What i can't figure out is why this happens. If i'm able to statically change the centre and solids are d

Comment: _“If i'm able to statically change the centre and solids are d”_… looks like you need to [edit] your question, because there’s something missing.

Comment: You’ve got a bunch of event listeners like this: `centre[…]=event.srcElement.value;`. Did you mean to pass an argument called `event` to the callback function for your `change` listeners, like this: `document.getElementById(…).onchange = function(event) {centre[…]=event.srcElement.value;};`?

Comment: I would make sure that `event.srcElement.value` is not a string or have some weird value

Comment: @Xufox got it right, you use `event` but the *event handler* need to be `function(event)`, as alternative I think you can just use `centre[...]=this.value` (`this` within the handler should be bounded to the element with `onchange`)

Comment: Please update your question: SO guidelines say *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. *

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I'm new to programming and just started learning JavaScript and HTML. What fixed my problem was what @Alex suggested. I didn't realize that the variables were being passed as string.